# Verify that the function $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2-y$ is harmonic

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-functions

How do I verify that the function
$$u(x,y)=x^2-y^2-y$$
is harmonic

Comment: What is the definition of harmonic? Do you know how to take partial derivatives?

Comment: What's the definition of a function being harmonic? Check that your $u$ satisfies it.

Answer (score 4):

$$u_{xx}=2\;\;,\;u_{yy}=-2\Longrightarrow \Delta u=...?$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the real part of $z^2 +iz$, therefore harmonic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x,y)=ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

So, $u_x=2ax+2hy+2g, u_{xx}=2a$

Similarly, $u_{yy}=2b$

Using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicFunction.html), we need $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ and $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=2(a+b)\implies b=-a$